# How to install Eclipse CDT Oxygen on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

What is the correct way to install Eclipse CDT Oxygen.0 on Ubuntu 16.04?

I want to install Eclipse CDT from scratch, i.e. I do not yet have Eclipse installed on my system at all.

I have downloaded the latest version of the Eclipse package (which, at the time of my writing this is "CDT 9.3.1 for Eclipse Oxygen") from https://eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php.

The downloaded file is called `eclipse-cpp-oxygen-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz`. Extracting this file results in a folder called `eclipse` that contains an executable called `eclipse`.

Now what?

I don't see an installer, but there also doesn't seem to be a need to "install" anything, I can just run the eclipse executable from right there. Should I just manually move the `eclipse` folder to `/opt` or some other directory? But now it won't be managed by APT?

The Eclipse website does not give any instructions as to how to perform the install properly.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can leave the folder in any place you like. Why do you want/need it to be managed by apt?

Comment: @Katu thanks for your comment! Are there no advantages to having everything managed by apt?

Comment: the version in the website is usually more updated than the one in the apt repos. I wouldn't worry about apt, but that's your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to install anything, as you mentioned just move the extracted folder `eclipse` to `/opt`, then you could make a symbolic link to the executable with `sudo ln -sv /opt/eclipse/eclipse /usr/local/bin/eclipse`. When you have done these steps you can run Eclipse with the simple command `eclipse`. 
 
It's not managed by `apt` because you didn't install it via `apt` (`sudo apt install eclipse`), that Eclipse that you find in the `apt` repository it's an old version of the Java IDE.